# How can I save image without frame in python?

Tags: image, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library, figure

I am plotting image by wavelet coefficients but I don't know how to save it without frame. I tried to do this by `plt.savefig` but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1=coeffs
for i, ci in enumerate(coeffs): 
        plt.imshow(ci.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, 3844, i + 0.5, i + 1.5],cmap='inferno',aspect='auto',interpolation='nearest') 
        plt.ylim(0.5, len(coeffs) + 0.5) 
        plt.yticks(range(1, len(coeffs) + 1), ['cA5', 'cD5', 'cD4', 'cD3', 'cD2', 'cD1'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'without frame' ? You want to remove the white border around the plot in the saved figure ? You want to remove the white background of the figure ?

Comment: @Liris without x-axis and y-axis. I want just the image.Yes I want to remove the borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to fit your image. Use `plt.axis('off')` before `plt.savefig`

For example, we have the following image.

[image]

We can use:

- `plt.axis('off')` remove the axis
- `plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')`

Output:

[image]

Code

---

```
scale = plt.imread(fname='27BR1.jpg')
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(scale, interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

***Possible Question:*** There is still a white area under the background?

---

Answer: Then you can use `opencv`

---

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('27BR1.jpg')
cv2.imwrite("test.png", img)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. I wonder if there is another way to remove the white area under the background. `opencv2` didn't work with me.

Comment: Glad, if I could help? did you install opencv: `pip install opencv-python`? or what error are you having?

Comment: yes I have installed `opencv` I have more than 1000 images when I run the code I got this error `error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:738: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite`

Comment: The error is about reading the image paths. You need to give a full-image path as an input. For instance: `C:\\Users\\..\\..\\my_image.png`

Comment: I have more than 1000 images if I write the path in this way `C:\\Users\\..\\..\\my_image.png` I will remove the white area from only one image. I want to remove the white area for all of the images.

Comment: No, no, don't do it like that. What is the extension of your images? Are they all same? For instance: Are they all ends with  '.png'?

Comment: If they are the same, use `glob` like `images = glob("C:\\Users\\..\\..\\*.png")` Then you will get all `.png` images. Then use `cv2.imread`

Comment: Yes they are the same. okay first I will use `images = glob("C:\\Users\\..\\..\\*.png")` then I will use `cv2.imread`. But what I should write inside the brackets ?? `img = cv2.imread(???)` ??

Comment: After storing all images using `glob`, you will get each image using a `for` loop: `for image in images: img = cv2.imread(image)` Of course don2T forget the indendation :)

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help :) :)

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)